# Combine two dataframes conditionally with dates

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dataframe, count

I am using two differrent data frames. I would like to complete one using the information that is contained in the other. The first data frame contains a list of observations of individual young animals whose birthdate and natal territory are known. The second data frame contains observations of adult animals that were present in given territories within given time intervals.
Here is a reproducible example:

```
#First dataframe:
ID_young <- c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each=3), "d") # All individuals observed three times except "d", observed once
Territory_young <- c(rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each=3), "x") # All individuals are from different territories, except "a" and "d" who are from the same territory, namely "x".
Birthdate <- c(rep(c("2014-01-29", "2014-12-17", "2013-11-19"), each=3), "2012-12-04")
Birthdate <- as.Date(Birthdate)

# Second dataframe:
ID_adult <- c("e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "e","f")
Territory_adult <- c("x", "x", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "w")
First_date <- as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-15", "2013-12-14", "2013-05-17", "2013-05-09", "2012-09-01", "2013-06-18", "2011-04-17"))
Last_date <- as.Date(c("2014-02-28", "2014-04-17", "2014-11-02", "2014-01-13", "2015-01-03", "2013-04-17", "2013-12-25", "2014-11-11"))

# Data frames complete:
df1 <- data.frame(ID_young, Territory_young, Birthdate)
df2 <- data.frame(ID_adult, Territory_adult, First_date, Last_date)
```

My goal is to create a new column in df1 that consists of the number of adult animals present in the young animal's territory at the time of its birth.
In other words,

For each line of df1:

- find the corresponding territory in df2
- count the number of lines in df2 where the interval between df2$First_date and df2$Last_date includes df1$Birthdate
- fill in that number in the new column of df1

For example, for the first three lines of df1 (corresponding to the young animal "a"), that count would be 2, because adults "e" and "f" were present in territory "x" when young "a" was born (2014-01-29).

Could someone help me formulate the right combination of conditional statements that would allow me to do that? I am trying for and if statements at the moment but have nothing worth showing.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide desired output and what you have tried

Comment: Try with `foverlaps` from `data.table`

Comment: I just gave one example of what the resulting number would be. I am trying `for` and `if` statements right now, but nothing worth showing. Are there any specific points that are unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nb.adults = apply(df1, 1, function(row, df2) {
  terr = as.character(row[2])
  bd = row[3]
  nb.adults = length(which(df2$First_date < bd & bd < df2$Last_date & 
df2$Territory_adult==terr))
  return(nb.adults)
}, df2)

df1 = cbind(df1, nb.adults)
```

Answer (score 1):

The recent versions of `data.table` support *non-equi joins* which can be used for this purpose:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# coerce to data.table
DT1 <- data.table(df1)
DT2 <- data.table(df2)

# right non-equi join to find any adults present in terrority during birth
DT2[unique(DT1), 
    on = c("Territory_adult==Territory_young", 
           "First_date<=Birthdate",
           "Last_date>=Birthdate")][
             # count adults for each young
             , .(Count_adult = sum(!is.na(ID_adult))), by = ID_young][
             # join counts into each matching row of first data.table
               DT1, on = "ID_young"]
```

> ```
>     ID_young Count_adult Territory_young  Birthdate
>  1:        a           2               x 2014-01-29
>  2:        a           2               x 2014-01-29
>  3:        a           2               x 2014-01-29
>  4:        b           0               y 2014-12-17
>  5:        b           0               y 2014-12-17
>  6:        b           0               y 2014-12-17
>  7:        c           3               z 2013-11-19
>  8:        c           3               z 2013-11-19
>  9:        c           3               z 2013-11-19
> 10:        d           0               x 2012-12-04
> ```

Note that `df1` and `DT1`, resp., contain duplicate rows which require to use `unique()` in the non-equi join with the adults and to use another join finally to make sure that the adults count appears on each row.